# Php: how to compute the different between two arrays of "similar" objects?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects `$tab` that are "rows" of a table (i.e. you can access each column through "`$tab[$i]->columnname`.

I have another array of objects `$tab_json` that is the return of an AJAX call, and that contains, *too*,  "rows" of a table (i.e. you can access each column through "`$tab_json[$i]->columnname`.

**Both** arrays contain exactly the same colums, but I would just like to "guess" which ones in `$tab` are **not** present in `$tab_json`.

Of course I know [array-intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-intersect.php) and [array-diff](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-diff.php) functions, but they do not seem to work well on objects comparison. Unless I'm wrong?

Here's a sample that I'd like to work, but there's a Php exception:

```
tab_json = PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in sample.php on line 112
```

Just copy paste it and run it into a file (`php -f filename.php`). Any idea how I should do?

```
<?php
$tab = array(
    (object)array(
        'id'          => 1,
        'titre'       => "Anchois",
        'attributs'   => array()
    ),  
    (object)array(
        'id'          => 4,
        'titre'       => "Jambon",
        'attributs'   => array()
    ),  
    (object)array(
        'id'           => 12, 
        'titre'        => "La Cabro d'or",
        'attributs'    => array(
            (object)array("id" => 1), 
            (object)array("id" => 8)
        )   
    )   
);


$tab_json = array (
    (object)array(
        'id' => 1,
        'titre' => 'Anchois',
        'attributs' =>
        array (
        ),  
    ),  
    (object)array(
        'id' => 4,
        'titre' => 'Jambon',
        'attributs' =>
        array (
        ),  
    ),  
    (object)array(
        'id' => 12, 
        'titre' => 'La Cabro d\'or',
        'attributs' =>
        array (
        ),  
    ),  
    (object)array(
        'id' => 25, 
        'titre' => 'Vin rouge ou rosé',
        'attributs' =>
        array (
        ),  
    ),  
    (object)array(
        'id' => 22, 
        'titre' => 'Crème oignons lardons',
        'attributs' =>
        array (
            (object)array(
                'id' => 1,
            ),  
            (object)array(
                'id' => 2,
            ),  
        ),  
    )   
);
echo "tab = "; var_export($tab); echo "\n";
echo "tab_json = "; var_export($tab_json); echo "\n";
echo "tab_json = "; var_export(array_diff($tab_json,$tab)); echo "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Are you comparing identical objects or different objects with identical data?

Comment: Objects with same properties but **maybe less** objects, or **maybe** properties values have changed (it's what I want to guess actually)

Comment: I've just added a concrete sample that I'd like to work.

Comment: In your example. what are you *wanting* the output to be?  The `attributs` of the object with `title == 'La Cabro d'or'` is different that the one from `$tab_json`, so would it appear in the diff?

Comment: No, it's not different. I want to see in the result (remember: it's json *minus* original array): the objects with ids 22 and 25 (= the ones that are not in the original array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made the function that seems to compare "ok": I "concatenate" the properties of both arrays to make "strings" then use the strcmp() function to return the result.
So, when the values are different they're changed to string, and when it comes to "sub" arrays, they're converted to string = "`Array`" so the comparison == 0 so the "sub" arrays are ignored (which is precisely what I wanted).

It works. If you find an example that could show me that it doesn't work, please share it with me in a comment. Thanks!

```
$difference = array_udiff($tab_json, $tab, function($a, $b) {
    $d=array_diff_assoc(get_object_vars($a), get_object_vars($b));
    if (count($d)>0) {
        $s0='';
        $s1='';
        foreach ($d as $k=>$val) {
            $r0=(string)$val;
            $r1=(string)$b->$k;
            $l0 = mb_strlen($r0);
            $l1 = mb_strlen($r1);
            for (;$l0<$l1;$l0++) {
                $r0=' '.$r0;
            }   
            for (;$l1<$l0;$l1++) {
                $r1=' '.$r1;
            }   
            $s0.=$r0;
            $s1.=$r1;
        }   
        return strcmp($s0,$s1);
    }   
    return 0;
});
echo "difference = "; var_export($difference); echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_udiff`:

```
$difference = array_udiff($tab, $tab_json, function($a, $b) {
    return $a == $b;
});
```

The simple `array_diff` can't be used because it only compares string values identically. PHP 5.3 is required to run this sample, but you can tweak it to PHP 5.2 moving the closure to an external function and passing the name of it as the third parameter on `array_udiff`.

Note that the order on `array_udiff` matters. If you pass `$tab_json` first you can get different results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work with the sample I've just added in my question: it returns empty array.

Comment: If I try this code for the closure: `return (count(array_diff(get_object_vars($a), get_object_vars($b))))>0;` it doesn't work, but the result is not an empty array (I may be closer now from a valuable solution). Still searching.

Comment: Do you have a sample for the objects you're comparing?

Comment: Yes the sample is in the... sample I've added in my question.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't noticed that. When comparing with '==' array comparison is always false (http://tehplayground.com/#vQD6qdH08). The count line you provided also don't work because depends on array_diff that has the same problem with sub-array comparison. You need to detect arrays inside objects and deal with them.

Comment: I've found a solution. It's not very clean but it works, I'll go on with that. I've posted it as an answer. Thank you very much for your answer, you put me on the right track!