# compare multi-dimensional arrays and return they keys who's values are different in php from the first array

Tags: php

I have two multi-dimensional array I want to take only those array  whose
key values are different from the first array

Here is my two array:

```
$array1 =  Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [serial] => k-0001
        [u_rec_id] => 1
        [employer_office] => uouuououou
        [job_type] => ouuou
        [job_title] => u
        [job_appointment_date] => 2013-07-15
        [job_duration] => ouu

    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [serial] => k-0001
        [u_rec_id] => 1
        [employer_office] => DDC
        [job_type] => Manger
        [job_title] => Manager
        [job_appointment_date] => 2013-07-17
        [job_duration] => one year
          )


 )
```

and this is my second array

```
$array2 =  Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [serial] => k-0001
        [u_rec_id] => 1
        [employer_office] => uouuououou
        [job_type] => ouuou
        [job_title] => u
        [job_appointment_date] => 2013-07-15
        [job_duration] => ouu

    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [serial] => k-0001
        [u_rec_id] => 1
        [employer_office] => ouo
        [job_type] => uououo
        [job_title] => udds
        [job_appointment_date] => 2013-07-17
        [job_duration] => uo
          )


 );
```

I tried array_diff and array_diff_assoc it also not worked for me
 i get this error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Array to string conversion

Filename: history/home.php

Line Number: 729

Comment: http://de2.php.net/array_diff this could help you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you there, depending on what exactly you want:

```
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, function (array $a, array $b) {
    return (int)array_diff($a, $b);
});
```

Adjust the comparison function to compare what exactly you want to compare.
http://php.net/array_udiff

Comment: No that does not works. I need to get that array if its key values changed

Comment: Well then, adjust the comparison function. I don't fully understand what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach`, `array_unique` and possibly `array_udiff` should help you here.

PHP Manual:

- [Unique Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- [Data Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php)
- [For Each](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

For a simple array:

```
$result = array_unique($array);
```

In your case there's a function from PHP Manual for this:

```
<?php 
function specified_array_unique($array, $value) 
{ 
    $count = 0; 

    foreach($array as $array_key => $array_value) 
    { 
        if ( ($count > 0) && ($array_value == $value) ) 
        { 
            unset($array[$array_key]); 
        } 

        if ($array_value == $value) $count++; 
    } 

    return array_filter($array); 
} 
?>
```

There's been a post that is similar to what you're asking;
[Stack Overflow - array_udiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269932/php-how-to-compute-the-different-between-two-arrays-of-similar-objects/10269976#10269976)